# Cannot run Windows Azure project due to Error: Unable to find fileDFUI.exe please verify your install is correct

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-storage

I am getting the following error, whenever I add an existing Asp.Net web application as existing web role project.

---

Microsoft Visual Studio
Unable to find fileDFUI.exe please verify your install is correct.

OK

---

I am using Nov 2011 SDK via WPI.
Steps to recreate:

1. Create an empty Azure project (without any role).
2. Add an existing  Asp.Net MVC3 project to the solution.
3. Right click on role to "Add an existing web role project in solution" to point to just added project.
4. Rebuild and run to see the error.

Please help.

Comment: Your steps to reproduce did not work for me (everything went just fine). Try uninstall and  then perform full install once again for the SDK and Tools. And keep runnig the Visual Studio as Administrator when developing Windows Azure Apps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Credit goes to Carson Wa from Microsoft who answered this one on msdn forums.**

The cause of the issue is that visual studio tries to load DFUI.exe from AppData temp directory, i.e. C:\Users\\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\GPO8L9XL.JW4\X9X8K6MA.13N\139aad8f\00a876bf_fa99cc01\DFUI.exe

DFUI.exe doesn't exist in AppData directory so visual studio reports the error. In SDK 1.5, visual studio reads a registry key to find the correct location. However it looks like that the registry lookup is removed in SDK 1.6.

Currently one of the workarounds is to copy ALL the files under C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Emulator\emulator to the AppData temp directory. Note the temp directory path may be different on your machine. You can find the path by using Process Monitor.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645
Please run process monitor and reproduce the issue in visual studio. Search DFUI.exe in the log and you will find the path.

Thanks,

Carson

Comment: Yes, it's very annoying and I can't believe Microsoft hasn't fixed it yet almost 6 months later...

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same error...

The Nov 2011 Azure Toolkit seems to check the correct folder (according to the Process Monitor), but you also get this error if you simply have the Azure Deployment project set as the startup project instead of your website.

Good to see you found the problem with the SQL instance name... guess there is more than one way to upset Azure.

Comment: Good one! Did not copy anything, somehow the start up project was changed to the Azure project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need that uploaded in your project (the Azure Compute Emulator User Interface from the SDK)?

If not, remove it from the existing ASP.NET project that has it in. Redeploy to Azure and it should be fine?

Comment: Not sure why Visual Stdio throwing this error. I have not included the emulator UI to project. It is just the default project template. All I trying is... to add an existing Asp.Net MVC3 application as a web role.

Answer (score 1):

Very key thing to note indeed:

"**Note the temp directory path may be different on your machine**. You can find the path by using Process Monitor. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645 Please run process monitor and reproduce the issue in visual studio. Search DFUI.exe in the log and you will find the path"

Answer (score 0):

I tried following without success:

1. Reinstalled Windows Azure Nov 2011 SDK.
2. DFUI.exe does exists in C:\Program Files\Windows Azure Emulator\emulator\devfabric

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Windows7 x64 Ultimate and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (v10.50.1617.0). SQL Server instance do not use default name "SQLExpress".

I could recreate the issue with another machine with similar configuration.

Storage emulator was not starting due to SQL Server instance name not being "SQLExpress". I configured the storage emulator using DSInit /sqlInstance:. It fixed the storage emulator. On manually started both storage and compute emulators and a restart to Visual Studio 2010, I can no longer see this error.

Moral of the story... Don't change the default name of your SQL Server Express instance ("SQLExpress"), unless you have a very good reason for it.

Edit: The error is back. Not sure what is the cause now. Unmarked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, installing MVC 3 from the asp.net website fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler answer, at least it worked for me.

I had two instances of Visual Studio running. I closed one and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error frequently (and fixed it as the other answers) but I have't had do it since installing the Azure SDK 1.7