# How can I pass along an XML content file to an dll in Windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Trying to integrate a dll which seems to require an xml file in a .net 4.0 C# PowerPoint Add-In this error occurs whenever calling a method from the dll:

```
Error: Could not find file 'C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\6ZEM2ZRW.ODN\V57AVN2Y.7LO\c7a2a88f\00b83183_9e96c501\ASCII.xml'.
```

The xml file in questions is included in the project as "Content" with "Copy to output directory = always".

To me it looks like Visual Studio loads the dll into a kind of "local assembly directory" instead of using it directly from the output?

I have the source of the [original dll library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10949/ASCII-Art-Generator?rp=/KB/web-image/AsciiArt/AsciiArtGenGui.zip#_rating) and a [sample c# project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/AsciiArt/AsciiArtGenGui.zip) implementing it.

In the dll it seems to be referenced like this:

```
    public const string DefaultAsciiDataFile = @".\ASCII.xml";
```

In the sample project I could not find reference (using search in files), I'm not sure how the files get even loaded.

How can I get the dll to find the xml?

Update: Just putting the xml file into this temp file helps for now. Found the idea in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254858/cannot-run-windows-azure-project-due-to-error-unable-to-find-filedfui-exe-pleas).

Maybe it's related to my project being an add-in?

(Ideally without modifying / rebuilding the dll)