# I get "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectNode' threw an exception." when opening ccproj files after installing Azure SDK 2.9

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution with an Azure cloud project in it that's targeting the 2.7 version of the Microsoft Azure SDK which I could open/build and deploy without problems. Since Visual Studio was nagging me to update, I went ahead and installed the new Azure SDK version of 2.9. After that update, I cannot open the cloud project files, and Visual Studio (2015 Community edition, now fully updated to the latest as of the time I'm writing this) gives me this error message:

> MyTest.ccproj : error : The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectNode' threw an exception.

I am able to open the project if I manually edit the ccproj file and change the

```
<ProductVersion>2.7</ProductVersion>
```

value to 2.9. However, I can not use that, since other people are working on this project and they still want to remain on the 2.7 version of the Azure SDK, which is also currently deployed to production.

Is there a way to allow Visual Studio to open older versions of cloud projects? Do I have to uninstall the Azure SDK updates?

Thank you all!

Comment: You can make local changes to the project, just make sure you don't check them in. You would be better off downgrading back to 2.7 though.

Comment: I know, that's exactly how I manage now, but it's a bit of a pain in the neck, and I'm curious if there's another way... It's such a shame you can't have two versions of SDK living together apparently.

Comment: I'm happy if I can get one version of the Azure SDK to run properly, let alone two :)

Comment: Unfortunately, downgrading may not always be a viable or efficient option.  In my case, I work with another project that is using the 2.9 SDK.  So, I would have to upgrade and downgrade every time I switch between these projects.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is an issue with the SxS compatibility for 2.9.5 and previous versions.  This is very recently discovered and we are looking into a fix for the next version, but until then you will have to uninstall 2.9.

1. **Uninstall** the “Microsoft Azure tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
   2015 – v2.9” from add/remove programs
2. Run `msiexec /x {60473BF2-359B-43B3-AF6C-12BAC6C5BC3F}`. (For VS 2013, use
   `{438EED24-F35B-44E0-A2E2-675838273002}`) This should bring up the msi
   dialog to uninstall “Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
   Studio 2015 Core”
3. In add/remove programs, **repair** Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 – v2.7 (or v2.8 for people using that version).

Updating answer.  The most common GUIDs for #2 are :

- `{60473BF2-359B-43B3-AF6C-12BAC6C5BC3F}`
- `{438EED24-F35B-44E0-A2E2-675838273002}`

If you get an error "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed." try using `{8664E001-704C-4EFB-B68D-6A3DEF60BBEE}`.

---

The MSFT Support forum on this is [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88df50a7-c96e-45d0-ae03-140c589a3642/cannot-create-new-or-load-existing-azure-cloud-projects-within-visual-studio-2015?forum=vssetup)

Connect ticket is [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/3102964/cannot-create-new-or-load-existing-azure-cloud-projects-within-visual-studio-2015-after-updating-the-sdk-version-from-2-82-to-2-9)

Comment: You're telling me the tool devs don't have 900 versions of this installed like the rest of us ;)

Comment: Ouch. Thanks for your solution though, I guess we'll have to eagerly wait for the next version to come out... Maybe it would be worth pointing this out on a breaking changes section in the documentation or somewhere before more people fall into this unknowingly.

Comment: Has the issue been fixed yet?

Comment: Just got bit by this. The sad thing is that this is linked on the Microsoft main SDK page here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/. Can't it be removed until fixed?

Comment: what is SxS, please?

Comment: SxS = side by side.  In other words, both 2.9.5 and an older version (ie. 2.7 or 2.8) installed at the same time.

Comment: Is this seriously the solution? Completely uninstall a major version and avoid its use until Microsoft figures out a solution? This doesn't seem to be high priority as it is still occurring to this day.

Comment: {76683332-1D62-4AB6-BEC6-6558D83A1AD0} worked for me

Answer (score 7):

## **Solution:**

- Uninstall the “Microsoft Azure tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 – v2.9” from add/remove programs and any other v 2.9 components
- Run “msiexec /x {60473BF2-359B-43B3-AF6C-12BAC6C5BC3F}” or {8664E001-704C-4EFB-B68D-6A3DEF60BBEE}. (For VS 2013, use {438EED24-F35B-44E0-A2E2-675838273002}) This should bring up the msi dialog to uninstall “Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Core”
- In add/remove programs, repair Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 – v2.7 (or v2.8 for people using that version).

### **Exceptions:**

In certain situations this might not be enough. Still, there are solutions for these exceptions also. If you still get the error message you might want to have a clean install. To do that please use the following command: 
*Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product | Out-File c:\temp\.txt*

This will create a file in the location you specified with all packages installed on your computer. Search through that file and use:
msiexec /x <**any GUID you think necessary**>

You can check here what are the components the 2.8 (if that is the case for you) package contains so you would know what you should or should not have:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50041

After removing everything you should reinstall 2.8.2 using the web package installer and check if that works.

### **More Exceptions:**

At this point the original issue should be gone but you might run into one of the following errors I pasted at the end of the article. For the first error you should register the assembly. You can list the assemblies using:

**gacutil -l >yourassemblies.txt**

Simply open the Developer Command Prompt (available in Start Menu>App>Visual Studio) and run the command.

The dll can be found here: 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure

You can register it using the same prompt with this command: 
**gacutil /i yourdll.dll**

For the second exception:
Use procmon from here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Find the path that Visual Studio is searching in by capturing the VS process (devenv) while reproducing the error.

Copy the files from here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Emulator
to the path you discovered.

See also:
[Cannot run Windows Azure project due to Error: Unable to find fileDFUI.exe please verify your install is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254858/cannot-run-windows-azure-project-due-to-error-unable-to-find-filedfui-exe-pleas)

Assembly:

The "DeleteCurrentDeployment" task failed unexpectedly.System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.File name: 'Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'   at Microsoft.Cct.Debugging.DevFabricService..ctor()   at Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectNode.<>c.b__121_0()   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Func`1 valueFactory)   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Func`1 valueFactory)   at Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectNode.get_DevFabricService()   at Microsoft.Cct.CctBuildDeploymentTaskHost.DeleteCurrentDeployment()   at Microsoft.CloudExtensions.MSBuildTasks.DeleteCurrentDeployment.Execute()   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Missing file:

The "DeleteCurrentDeployment" task failed unexpectedly.Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabricException: Unable to find file 'DFUI.exe' please verify your install is correct.   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Utility.ProcessWrapper.ResolveBinaryFullPath(String binaryName)   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.Utility.ProcessWrapper..ctor(String binaryName, String arguments, Boolean breakAway)   at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabric..ctor(Boolean singleInstance)   at Microsoft.Cct.Debugging.DevFabricService..ctor()   at Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectNode.<>c.b__121_0()   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Func`1 valueFactory)   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Func`1 valueFactory)   at Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectNode.get_DevFabricService()   at Microsoft.Cct.CctBuildDeploymentTaskHost.DeleteCurrentDeployment()   at Microsoft.CloudExtensions.MSBuildTasks.DeleteCurrentDeployment.Execute()   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the effort and the detailed answer, I hope it will help someone struggling with this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Today a new SDK 2.9.6 was released [click](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/)

Maybe someone with this problem could try to install it and tell if proplems are solved without the need of other solutions.

Comment: I can confirm that 2.9.6 solved this issue for my team. We didn't do any of the "workarounds" described by other answers; we opted to wait for an official fix and it looks like 2.9.6 is it!

Comment: After having installed Azure SDK for .NET 2.9.6 I was able to load the cloud project successfully!

Answer (score 1):

I had to run msiexec /x {8664E001-704C-4EFB-B68D-6A3DEF60BBEE} to get this to work.

I tried commenting by lack the 50 points as well - sorry.

Comment: Same for me  thanks for posting this.  FYI, I had to re-repair the 2.7 toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the project loading by editing the project file and changing the SDK version to 2.9. At least then I could debug. It's a workaround while waiting, and so you don't mess up your machine uninstalling/reinstalling different SDKs. YMMV. Modify the following sections of the project file and reload:

First, change  to 2.9 from 2.8:

```
<ProductVersion>2.9</ProductVersion>
```

Then, in , same thing, as follows:

```
<CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\</CloudExtensionsDir>
```

I hope that helps! Worked for me :)

Comment: I've actually said this in my question that if I manually change the version number, it will load the project. The problem is that I cannot check that change in, since other people are also working on the project, and they did not upgrade their SDK version yet - so the ccproj will work on my machine but not theirs.

Answer (score 0):

install 2.8 sdk along with 2.7 already installed. This solved my prob

Answer (score 0):

I saw "user6258895" already have this solution. I just like to add some more:

I had the same problem. After installing Microsoft Azure SDK for .Net (Your Visual Studio Version) -- Take latest SDK Version, my solution is working fine.

The below tools i have installed for my Visual studio ultimate 2013. If you want you can download as per your visual studio version.

First try to install/repair "Microsoft Azure SDK for .Net (Your Visual Studio Version) -- Take latest SDK Version". See is it working or not.

1. Microsoft.Azure.HDInsightToolsForVS2013.msi
2. MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi
3. MicrosoftAzureComputeEmulator-x64.exe
4. MicrosoftAzureLibsForNet-x64
5. MicrosoftAzureQuickstarts.msi
6. MicrosoftAzureStorageEmulator.msi
7. MicrosoftAzureStorageTools.msi
8. MicrosoftAzureTools.VS110.exe --For VS 2012
9. MicrosoftAzureTools.VS120.exe --For VS 2013
10. MicrosoftAzureTools.VS140.exe -- --For VS 2015
11. VWDOrVs2013AzurePack.exe ---Try to install it first to see, if it works.
12. WebToolsExtensionsVS2013.msi

Or you can google by Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET - 2.6 (Use your required version)

N.B: Change the version according to your PC/VS configuration.

Thank you.