# Does cspack.exe support .NET 4.6*?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, .net-4.6, cspack

According to [Support and Retirement Information for the Azure SDK for .NET and APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479282.aspx), SDK 2.6 introduced support for .NET 4.6. None of the listed SDKs explicitly mention 4.6.2 though the sister article [Install .NET on a Cloud Service Role](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-install-dotnet/) includes an installation script that explicitly installs .NET 4.6.2, implying that it is supported for web/worker roles.

When I attempted to upgrade my solution from .NET 4.5.1 (using Azure SDK 2.8) to .NET 4.6.2, I also modified my `RoleProperties.txt` file which included the following lines:

`TargetFrameWorkVersion=v4.5.1
RoleTargetFramework=v4.5.1`

to

`TargetFrameWorkVersion=v4.6.2
RoleTargetFramework=v4.6.2`

which resulted in the following error after calling `cspack.exe`:

> Unsupported .Net Framework v4.6.2

I tried changing the `4.6.2` to simply `4.6` and that similarly failed.

**So my questions are:**

1. How do you correctly target .NET 4.6.2 using `cspack.exe`?
2. Is it necessary to set those properties to `4.6*` or is it safe to leave them at `4.5.1` since `cspack.exe` doesn't complain?

Comment: Have you found any solution yet? I can currently package my application (.NET 4.6) with the newest SDK (2.9.5) but the deployment fails. For more info see disq.us/p/1dglsdr

Comment: Although I believe the error is effectively just a warning (the .nupkg is still produced), I have been unsuccessful in deploying my web/worker roles with 4.6+. I have yet to try with OS family 5 because because it requires Azure SDK 2.9.5.1+ which is [currently broken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39372220/607701) and [not slated to be fixed until the end of November](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix/#comment-2977814498).

Comment: Reporting back that I successfully deployed my app on OS family 5 running .NET 4.6.2. I was never able to get self-installed .NET 4.6.2 to work.

Comment: I have the same problem with cloud service, when targeting os family 5. The compilation of the cloud service fails with that error...

Comment: We found this which help us with similar issues: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-cloud-services-files/tree/master/Azure%20Targets%20SDK%202.9